# Custom Pinch To Zoom View

Tags: android, xml, zooming

I am trying to implement Pinch To Zoom on an Android app I am working on. For this, I have made a Java Class called PinchToZoom using the Android developer's website. However, if I try to launch my app I get an error in my XML file. I am confused as to why though, because I thought I had implemented it correctly. This is the XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#222222"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.andriesse.athena.PinchToZoom
    android:id="@+id/selectedImage"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope you guys can help me out!

**EDIT:**

I forgot to add the error log before, so here it is:

```
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.andriesse.athena/com.andriesse.athena.ImageEditing}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.andriesse.athena.PinchToZoom
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.andriesse.athena.PinchToZoom
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:589)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at com.andriesse.athena.ImageEditing.onCreate(ImageEditing.java:26)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     ... 11 more
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:561)
10-03 13:35:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     ... 22 more
```

Comment: Sorry, my telepathy widget isn't working either.  What error?

Comment: I'm sorry, it was quite late at night when I posted this and I must have been very tired to forget the error log. I have posted it now, however!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the key line:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
```

Make sure that your custom listview has these constructors:

```
public PinchToZoom(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public PinchToZoom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {   // <--- missing?
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public PinchToZoom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    // initialisation code here
}
```

I've chained them this way so you never have to do anything except in the 3rd constructor.  If you have these constructors, and they don't have external dependencies that can only be resolved at runtime, your custom listview will also preview correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an xml node of type com.andriesse.athena.PinchToZoom, try creating one of type view and giving it a class attribute of class= "com.andriesse.athena.PinchToZoom", like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#222222"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <view
        class="com.andriesse.athena.PinchToZoom"
        android:id="@+id/selectedImage"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: also, instead of writing your own pinch-zoom code, you may want to try using this: https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview

I used it on a previous project and it worked great for me.